# Should [ll] and [lr] be renamed?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Should tags [lr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lr) and [ll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ll) be renamed to [lr-grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lr-grammar) [ll-grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ll-grammar) respectively?

For the general public, these two letters might mean anything:

- [ll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ll) : [LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70938689/1000000000010-returning-8-in-java), [Low Level API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319739/stm32-unable-to-exit-interrupt-handler-for-uart-interrupt), [roman two(?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376928/how-does-token-endpoint-knows-about-user-authenticated-during-authorization-code),
- [lr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lr) : [Learning rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67020025/get-learning-rate-from-tensorflow-python-keras-optimizer-v2-learning-rate-sched), [Loadrunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073948/unable-to-record-https-application-in-vugen-loadrunner), [link register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66336711/arm64-backtrace-from-link-register)

I believe, the addition of "-grammar" should clarify the intended use of these tags even for most inattentive users.

---

**Edit:** since this idea has general support (based on votes), no objections, and all incorrectly tagged questions were re-tagged, please consider this as a request for renaming.

Comment: It looks like I've retagged all questions with these tags that were unrelated to grammars: [lr](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blr%5D+-%5Bgrammar%5D+-%5Bll%5D+-%5Bparsing%5D+-grammar+is%3Aq), [ll](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bll%5D+-%5Bgrammar%5D+-%5Blr%5D+-%5Bparsing%5D+is%3Aq+-grammar)

Comment: Some other Unixy names are [as/gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler) (not to be confused with [Ethereum's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethereum#Gas) gas or [Google Apps Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps_Script))), [ar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)), and [as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_(Unix)).

Comment: @PeterMortensen, sorry, I miss how is this related to this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completed by Dharman's efforts. Both tags renamed.